# How to format number to varchar with thousand separator? Like oracle to_char()

Tags: sql, format, firebird, to-char

Who knows how in Firebird 3 format number to varchar with thousand separator? Like oracle to_char ()
select to_char(1234325234234.55,'999G999G999G999G999D00' ) nn from dual
-- 1 234 325 234 234,55

Comment: write is as FB3 Stored Function

basically you need to convert float to varchar, then to insert spaces (or whatever thousand separator you would use)

Answer (score 2):

Here, this may help. Sorry for the spanish comments, I coded it for my work.

cheers!

```
SET TERM ^ ;

create or alter procedure FN_FORMATEA_NUMERO_MILES (
    PVALOR numeric(14,2))
returns (
    NUMERO_FORMATEADO varchar(20))
as
declare variable VDECIMALES varchar(2);
declare variable VENTEROS varchar(20);
declare variable VNUMERO_BASE varchar(20);
declare variable VCONTEO smallint;
declare variable VDIGITOS smallint;
begin
  /* Convierte el numero a caracter */
  vnumero_base = trim(cast(pvalor as varchar(20)));
  /* Separa el segmendo decimal del segmento de enteros */
  vdecimales = substring(vnumero_base from position('.', vnumero_base) + 1 for 2);
  venteros = substring(vnumero_base from 1 for position('.', vnumero_base) - 1);
  /* Inicializa el resultado */
  numero_formateado = '.' || vdecimales;
  /* Integra los enteros en grupos de 3 */
  vconteo = char_length(venteros);
  vdigitos = 0;
  while (vconteo > 0) do
  begin
    numero_formateado = substring(venteros from vconteo for 1) || numero_formateado;
    vconteo = vconteo - 1;
    vdigitos = vdigitos + 1;
    if ((vdigitos = 3) and (vconteo > 0) and (substring(venteros from vconteo for 1) <> '-')) then
    begin
      vdigitos = 0;
      numero_formateado = ',' || numero_formateado;
    end
  end
  /* Regresa el numero formateado */
  suspend;
end^

SET TERM ; ^

/* Existing privileges on this procedure */

GRANT EXECUTE ON PROCEDURE FN_FORMATEA_NUMERO_MILES TO SYSDBA;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such option in Firebird. If you need something like that you'll need to build it yourself as an UDF (or look for an existing third party UDF that does this), or as a (Firebird 3+) stored function.

Comment: Can you help convert this UDF F_FIXEDPOINTLANG from http://freeadhocudf.org function to Firebird 3 psql function?

Comment: @GoodBit No, sorry, I can't.